# Usage of JPA in SpringBoot

Tags: java, jquery, sql, jpa

I made this query but I'm not sure if there's a way not to use native query.
I need to find the count of the team plan subscription (of an smsplan) that is using this certain outgoing rate card.

```
String fetchTotalTeamPlanSubscriptionByOutgoingRateCard = "SELECT count(*) FROM team_plan_subscription WHERE plan_id IN " +
        "(SELECT sms_plan.id FROM sms_plan sms_plan INNER JOIN outgoing_sms_rate_card rate_card " +
        "ON rate_card.id = sms_plan.outgoing_sms_rate_card_id" +
        " WHERE sms_plan.outgoing_sms_rate_card_id = :outgoingSmsRateCardId);";

@Query(value = fetchTotalTeamPlanSubscriptionByOutgoingRateCard, nativeQuery = true)
public long fetchTotalTeamPlanSubscriptionByOutgoingRateCard(long outgoingSmsRateCardId);
```

I tried this but it seems it's not working
`public long countTeamPlanSubscriptionByPlan_Id_OutgoingSmsRateCardId(long outgoingSmsRateCardId);`

I get an error of `Cannot resolve property`

Here are the entities

```
public class TeamPlanSubscription {
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = SmsPlan.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    SmsPlan plan;
}
```

```
public class SmsPlan {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = OutgoingSmsRateCard.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private OutgoingSmsRateCard outgoingSmsRateCard;
}
```

```
public class SmsPlan {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = OutgoingSmsRateCard.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private OutgoingSmsRateCard outgoingSmsRateCard;
}
```

```
public class OutgoingSmsRateCard {

    @Id
    @Getter
    private Long id;

}
```

Comment: Attach exception stacktrace please

Comment: Hi Alex. The error is in IDE.

Comment: is your `fetchTotalTeamPlanSubscriptionByOutgoingRateCard` static?

Comment: no. :( is there a way not to use a native query here?

Comment: If it is declared in interface it is static. And what means `Th error is in IDE`?